# С#. Переопределение метода GetHashCode

Tags: c#, hashcode

Здравствуйте!

Возник вопрос по поводу переопределения метода `GetHashCode`.
Рассмотрим пример:

Есть класс `Container`, который просто хранит некоторые значения:

```
public class Container
{ 
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public bool IsFull { get; set; }
}
```

Для данного класса необходимо переопределить метод `GetHashCode`.

**Вопрос**: Есть ли какой-то шаблонный способ для реализации данного метода? Или здесь "у кого на что фантазии хватит"?

Приведу несколько примеров реализации методов, которые я смог найти и адаптировать к данному примеру (в ответе прошу объяснить, почему и в каких случаях та или иная реализация будет плохой или наоборот хорошей):

1. Самая банальная идея - использовать реализацию метода класса `Object` (знаю, что это глупо, но пусть для примера будет такая реализация):

   ```
   public override int GetHashCode()
   {
       return base.GetHashCode();
   }
   ```
2. Обычная сумма (или побитовая операция XOR) хеш-кодов всех свойств объекта:

   ```
   public override int GetHashCode()
   {
       unchecked
       {
           return Number.GetHashCode() + Text.GetHashCode() + IsFull.GetHashCode();
       }
   }
   ```
3. Некоторый специфический алгоритм (умножение хеш-кода на простое число и др.):

   ```
   public override int GetHashCode()
   {
       int hashcode = Number.GetHashCode();
       hashcode = 31 * hashcode + Text.GetHashCode();
       hashcode = 31 * hashcode + IsFull.GetHashCode();

       return hashcode;
   }
   ```

Comment: А какие данные уникально идентифицируют объект?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, Допустим, только свойства `Number` и `Text`. Понятно, что тогда в переопределении метода отпадет "слагаемое" `IsFull`.

Comment: Например, если у вас поле `Number` уникально идентифицирует объект, то просто верните `Number.GetHashCode()`. Главное, чтобы одинаковые объекты имели одинаковый хэшкод. Обратное не обязано быть верным, вот и всё.

Comment: @AndreiKhotko тогда считайте как комбинацию хэшкодов Number и Text. или просто как Number.GetHashCode (который возвращает Number :).

Comment: @PashaPash т.е. основной шаблон реализации данного метода - это сложение хеш-кодов?

Comment: @PashaPash не желаете оформить ответ к вопросу?

Comment: @AndreiKhotko Ваш вопрос — дубликат, на него не будет ответов, пока его не переоткроют. Что тоже очень вряд ли. По поводу сложения хэшкодов, нельзя сказать, что это лучше, чем вернуть `Number.GetHashCode()`.

Comment: @PashaPash вопрос ведь заключался не в том, как переопределить метод, а в том, каким способом(алгоритмом) лучше пользоваться. Я не считаю свой вопрос дубликатом. Я читал данный вопрос, но там не то, что я бы хотел увидеть.

Comment: @AndreiKhotko а что вы хотели увидеть? Ваш вопрос - Есть ли какой-то шаблонный способ для реализации данного метода. По ссылкам есть развернутый ответ на него. Выбираете пару полей, которые идентифицируют объект + остальные ограничения, про которые сказано по ссылке (типа неизменяемости, скорости и прочего) - и получаете готовую реализацию. Конкретный алгоритм при этом совершенно не важен, главное чтобы у результата было хорошее распределение (т.е. return 1 - плохая реализация :)

Comment: "Конкретный алгоритм при этом совершенно не важен, главное чтобы у результата было хорошее распределение (т.е. return 1 - плохая реализация" - эти слова я и хотел услышать :)

Answer (score -1):

Ну первая идея - действительно глупая (если хеш код планируется использовать), по одной простой причине: хеш код от object это хеш адреса объекта в памяти. Грубо говоря, два объекта с одинаковым содержимым буду выдавать разные хеши. Принципиально разные. Как следствие использовать их... Ну я думаю понятно).

А вот второй и третий имеют право на жизнь. Причем наверно ближе второй. Я не вижу если честно особой разницы в распределении (рандом умноженный на простое число остается рандомом), а возни меньше).

Кстати еще можно задать вопрос - для чего хеш будет использоваться? Если для словаря то пойдет второй. Если просто для сравнения объектов, проще `Equals` переопределить).

Comment: хеш код от object это хеш адреса объекта в памяти - это не так. сборщик мусора перекладывает обекты в памяти, и хэшкод при этом не меняется.

Comment: Это просто для примера привел класс. Для чего мне нужен хеш? Ну, это сложно объяснить, потому что это простой `Task` с курсов, где для класса нужно переопределить методы объекта). Объекты этого класса должны быть сравнимыми между собой (отношение эквивалентности и порядка). По поводу того, что достаточно переопределить метод `Equals`: после переопределения метода `Equals` компилятор выдает Warning: CS0659 "Container" переопределяет Object.Equals(object o), но не переопределяет Object.GetHashCode().

Comment: @PashaPash а можете вкратце объяснить, какая стандартная реализация для метода `object.GetHashCode` и на основе чего в таком случае вычисляется хеш?

Comment: @AndreiKhotko там рандом, результат которого запоминается в SyncBlock для объекта. Можете задать это отдельным вопросом. или почитать что-то готовое, вроде https://habrahabr.ru/post/188038/